# how can i track the people?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my project is about tracking people. so when i simulated my work in Gazebo, i launched the robot as the tracked people. and i used Hokuyo-04lx.

could anyone tell me how to write the code for tracking?

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140561/how-can-i-track-the-people?/) by [bestbesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/13411/bestbesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on 2014-03-17**:
using camera maybe  a good selection

**Comment by [bestbesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/13411/bestbesta/) on 2014-04-03**:
thank you for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a relatively open research problem. You'll need to do clustering and classification. And it will likely need to be tuned to your environment.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bestbesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/13411/bestbesta/) on 2014-04-03**:
thank you for your suggestion :)